# Как создать границу с градиентом, направленным перпендикулярно линии границы?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть на окне прямоугольная область со скруглёнными краями

```
 <Border BorderThickness="2" 
    Name="boder_panel" 
    CornerRadius="12">
 </Border>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать у этой области границу, которая посередине более светлая, чем по краям, т.е., как бы выступающая. Но когда я пытаюсь использовать `GradientBrush` для этого, получается, что градиент распространяется не поперёк границы, а свеху вниз или снизу вверх вдоль всей прямоугольной области.

Если бы не скруглённые края, я бы попробовал вдоль каждой из сторон поместить узенький прямоугольник с градиентом. И то, не совсем понятно, как разруливать их наложение друг на друга на углах. А со скруглёнными углами совсем непонятно, что делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете эскиз нарисовать того что хотите получить?

Comment: Нарисовал, как мог. Середина границ более светлая, чем края.